# angularjs changes in promise data not reflected in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to build a web application.
I have written a service which contains a method called getMatchedMenuItems(searchTerm)
The goal of this method is to connect to a REST API, retrieve data, process it(according to the searchTerm), and return the promise object.
In the controller, I'm called this method and trying to update a status variable, which is used on the ng-if attribute for a directive template.
This is the service code:

```
function MenuSearchService($http, $q){
var service = this;

service.getMatchedMenuItems = function(searchTerm){
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  if(searchTerm){
    $http(...)
    .then(function(response){
      //process data
      var returnItem = {
        items: foundItems,
        status: true
      }
      deferred.resolve(returnItem);
    });
  }
  else{
    var error = {
      message: 'Search term is empty',
      status: false
    };
    deferred.reject(error);
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
}
```

This is the controller:

```
function NarrowItDownController(MenuSearchService){
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.getSearchedItems = function(){
  MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems(ctrl.searchTerm)
  .then(function(data){
    ctrl.found = data.items;
    ctrl.status = data.status;
  }, function(error){
    alert(error.message);
    ctrl.status = error.status;
  });
};
ctrl.onRemove = function(index){
  ctrl.found.splice(index, 1);
};
}
```

This is the directive

```
function FoundItems(){
  var ddo = {
  templateUrl: 'foundItems.html',
  scope: {
    found: '<',
    onRemove: '&'
  }
};
return ddo;
}
```

The directive foundItems.html template

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.status">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.found">
       {{ item.name }}
       <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.onRemove({index: $index});">Don't want this one!</button>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using the template in index.html

```
<found-items found="ctrl.found" on-remove="ctrl.removeItem(index)" ng-if="ctrl.dataAvailable">
</found-items>
```

What is wrong with the code? The value of the ctrl.status variable get updated but that change is not reflected in the html

Comment: `onRemove()` is not `removeItem()`. The template is calling a function that does not exist in the parent controller.

Comment: @pankaj paker yes i do.

Comment: @georgeawg I don't understand that

Comment: @georgeawg I made that change. still no output. The changes made in the controller function to variables:ctrl.found and ctrl.status are not reflected in the HTML. I also removed the ng-if attribute from the template's HTML